# How to replace accented characters in the CQL filter, using GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, cql-filter, ajax

I have  GIS API based on OpenLayers and GeoServer. I want to perform an Ajax request in order to get all the features that have a given keyword.

For example, I could use the CQL filter:

```
name LIKE '%Setúbal%'
```

And I will get the feature corresponding to the portuguese district of "Setúbal".

Now, I wanted to simplify a bit and allow myself to write "setúbal".

I use the following CQL filter:

```
strToLowerCase(name) LIKE '%setúbal%'
```

It works fine, because the CQL function "strToLowerCase" successfully converts the text of the feature to lower case.

**--- UNTIL HERE, EVERYTHING WORKS FINE... THE PROBLEM COMES NEXT ---**

As you may have noticed, I want to simplify further by only writing "setubal" without the accented "u" ("ú").

I looked into the [Filter Function Reference of Geoserver](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#string-functions) and I found the "strReplace" method, which seemed to be exactly what I needed to replace the accented letters of the feature's attribute.

So, I tried these CQL filters:

```
// Replace the accented "u" and convert to lower case
strToLowerCase(strReplace(name, ú, u, true)) LIKE '%setubal%'

// Only replace the accented "u"
strReplace(name, ú, u, true) LIKE '%setubal%'
```

But neither of them work and I get this parser error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
    <ServiceException>Could not parse CQL filter list. Lexical error at line 1, column 18. Encountered: "\u00fa" (250), after : "" Parsing : strReplace(name, ú, u, true) LIKE '%setubal%'.</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I thought that the problem might be in using an accented letter in a CQL filter, and tried this:

```
strReplace(name, e, u, true) LIKE '%setubal%'
```

And even so, I get a parser error (but different than the previous one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
    <ServiceException>java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: PropertyDescriptor is null - did you request a property that does not exist? java.lang.NullPointerException: PropertyDescriptor is null - did you request a property that does not exist? PropertyDescriptor is null - did you request a property that does not exist?</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Am I using the "strReplace" function in a wrong way? Could anybody help with this issue, please? I want to replace accented characters in the CQL filter.

Comment: don't you need quotes around the u's ?

Comment: Hello @iant. You are absolutely right. I had tried with double-quotes (") and it didn't work either. Now, I have tried with simple-quotes (') and it worked. I can't believe I lost so much time around something so simple. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Write that as an answer so it will be easier to find from archives.